# Powershell becomes normal shell after running cmd

Tags: powershell

I want to use "start-ssh-agent.cmd" (is part of git for windows installation) from powershell. The problem is: if i run this in powershell my powershell becomes a normal shell. The prompt changes from "PS C:..." to "C:\". After this ps scripts won't run.
This is the script:

```
@REM Do not use "echo off" to not affect any child calls.

@REM Enable extensions, the `verify` call is a trick from the setlocal help
@VERIFY other 2>nul
@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    @ECHO Unable to enable extensions
    @GOTO failure
)

@REM Start the ssh-agent if needed by git
@FOR %%i IN ("git.exe") DO @SET GIT=%%~$PATH:i
@IF EXIST "%GIT%" @(
    @REM Get the ssh-agent executable
    @FOR %%i IN ("ssh-agent.exe") DO @SET SSH_AGENT=%%~$PATH:i
    @IF NOT EXIST "%SSH_AGENT%" @(
        @FOR %%s IN ("%GIT%") DO @SET GIT_DIR=%%~dps
        @FOR %%s IN ("!GIT_DIR!") DO @SET GIT_DIR=!GIT_DIR:~0,-1!
        @FOR %%s IN ("!GIT_DIR!") DO @SET GIT_ROOT=%%~dps
        @FOR %%s IN ("!GIT_ROOT!") DO @SET GIT_ROOT=!GIT_ROOT:~0,-1!
        @FOR /D %%s in ("!GIT_ROOT!\usr\bin\ssh-agent.exe") DO @SET SSH_AGENT=%%~s
        @IF NOT EXIST "!SSH_AGENT!" @GOTO ssh-agent-done
    )
    @REM Get the ssh-add executable
    @FOR %%s IN ("!SSH_AGENT!") DO @SET BIN_DIR=%%~dps
    @FOR %%s in ("!BIN_DIR!") DO @SET BIN_DIR=!BIN_DIR:~0,-1!
    @FOR /D %%s in ("!BIN_DIR!\ssh-add.exe") DO @SET SSH_ADD=%%~s
    @IF NOT EXIST "!SSH_ADD!" @GOTO ssh-agent-done
    @REM Check if the agent is running
    @FOR /f "tokens=1-2" %%a IN ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq ssh-agent.exe"') DO @(
        @ECHO %%b | @FINDSTR /r /c:"[0-9][0-9]*" > NUL
        @IF "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" @(
            @SET SSH_AGENT_PID=%%b
        ) else @(
            @REM Unset in the case a user kills the agent while a session is open
            @REM needed to remove the old files and prevent a false message
            @SET SSH_AGENT_PID=
        )
    )
    @REM Connect up the current ssh-agent
    @IF [!SSH_AGENT_PID!] == []  @(
        @ECHO Removing old ssh-agent sockets
        @FOR /d %%d IN (%TEMP%\ssh-??????*) DO @RMDIR /s /q %%d
    ) ELSE  @(
        @ECHO Found ssh-agent at !SSH_AGENT_PID!
        @FOR /d %%d IN (%TEMP%\ssh-??????*) DO @(
            @FOR %%f IN (%%d\agent.*) DO @(
                @SET SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%%f
                @SET SSH_AUTH_SOCK=!SSH_AUTH_SOCK:%TEMP%=/tmp!
                @SET SSH_AUTH_SOCK=!SSH_AUTH_SOCK:\=/!
            )
        )
        @IF NOT [!SSH_AUTH_SOCK!] == [] @(
            @ECHO Found ssh-agent socket at !SSH_AUTH_SOCK!
        ) ELSE (
            @ECHO Failed to find ssh-agent socket
            @SET SSH_AGENT_PID=
        )
    )
    @REM See if we have the key
    @SET "HOME=%USERPROFILE%"
    @"!SSH_ADD!" -l 1>NUL 2>NUL
    @SET result=!ERRORLEVEL!
    @IF NOT !result! == 0 @(
        @IF !result! == 2 @(
            @ECHO | @SET /p=Starting ssh-agent:
            @FOR /f "tokens=1-2 delims==;" %%a IN ('"!SSH_AGENT!"') DO @(
                @IF NOT [%%b] == [] @SET %%a=%%b
            )
            @ECHO. done
        )
        @"!SSH_ADD!"
        @ECHO.
    )
)

:ssh-agent-done
:failure

@ENDLOCAL & @SET "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%SSH_AUTH_SOCK%" ^
          & @SET "SSH_AGENT_PID=%SSH_AGENT_PID%"

@ECHO %cmdcmdline% | @FINDSTR /l "\"\"" >NUL
@IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 @(
    @CALL cmd %*
)
```

So how to get back powershell after running this in powershell or better how to prevent it at all?

Comment: At the prompt Type "exit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executing a .cmd file a command prompt is opened within Powershell. All you have to is to exit the cmd by typing "exit".

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

IMHO there are 2 better alternatives to the chosen answer:

#### 1) Use `cmd /c`

```
cmd /c "start-ssh-agent.cmd"
```

That will execute the powershell script inside a cmd session, without keeping it open (so you don't have to type `exit` afterwards).

```
CMD.EXE /?
...
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```

#### 2) Use `posh-git`

Install [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) and then use its `Start-SshAgent` function. It is the PowerShell counterpart to the `start-ssh-agent.cmd` script.